# Match decimal numbers

Tags: regex, pcre

I would like to match decimal numbers like:

```
0.0
0.12
1.00
1.12
-0.123
-1.000
-1.123
```

without matching negative zeros: `-0.0` or `-0.00`, `-0.000` etc.

I have no idea how to extend the `/^-?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/` regex to not to allow negative zeros.

UPDATE:

- No leading zeros allowed: 01.1 or -01.1
- Whole and fractional characters are required (.5 or 5. not allowed)

Comment: It would help if you mentioned a particular flavour of regexps you're targeting.

Comment: Are those lines each individual strings (as I assumed), or are you matching a multiline text file with the `m` flag?

Comment: Do you have any non-decimal numbers in your input, or are they all decimal numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you just need to add a negative lookahead **`(?!-0\.0+$)`**:

```
^(?!-0\.0+$)-?\d+\.\d+$
```

Example:

```
echo '0.0
0.12
1.00
1.12
-0.123
-1.000
-1.123
-0.00
-0.0
-0.000010
-12.34
' | perl -lne 'print if /^(?!-0\.0+$)-?\d+\.\d+$/'
#0.0
#0.12
#1.00
#1.12
#-0.123
#-1.000
#-1.123
#-0.000010
#-12.34
```

Comment: Unfortunately it also matches leading zeros: 01.1, -01.1, 0012.12 etc.

Comment: check **^(?!-0\.0+$)-?(?:0|[1-9]\d*)\.\d+$**, so this will avoid leading zero when there are more than two digits before the dot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
^-?(?:0*[1-9][0-9]*\.[0-9]+|0\.0*[1-9][0-9]*)$
```

https://regex101.com/r/z51Jpu/5

The idea is, after matching the `-`, match either a non-zero in the integer part, or match a zero eventually followed by a non-zero.

- `^-?` - Beginning of the string, optional `-`
- `(?:[1-9]\.[0-9]*|0\.0*[1-9][0-9]*)` - Match either:

  - `0*[1-9][0-9]*\.[0-9]*` A non-zero integer part, followed by a decimal part or
  - `0\.0*[1-9][0-9]*` - A zero integer part, with a decimal part that has a non-zero somewhere
- `$` - End of string

Could also lookahead for a digit between 1 and 9 somewhere in the line, then use your original pattern:

```
^-?(?=[0.]*[1-9])[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

https://regex101.com/r/z51Jpu/6

Comment: It doesn't match 0.

Comment: OP doesn't have any numbers without fractional characters in his input (and his original pattern doesn't match those either) - unless OP says so, I think `0.` either won't happen, or shouldn't be matched

Comment: Nor does it match 0.0

Comment: Also fails on `-2.`.

Comment: Thought OP wanted to match only decimal numbers - *OP doesn't have any numbers without fractional characters in his input (and his original pattern doesn't match those either)*

Comment: Right, but yours does match `-2.`. Seems like that should be rejected along with any numbers in the form `.0` and `0.`, if I'm understanding correctly...

Comment: Is there any reason you have to match numbers this way?  Regex's can be expensive and there might be a quicker/better way to solve your problem.

Comment: Oh, the trailing digits, need to repeat with `+` instead of `*`

Comment: @WJS That's a question you should be asking OP, not me, but there's nothing wrong with a regex here IMO

Comment: @CertainPerformance Yes, i would like to match numbers with fractional characters.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a crude but effective approach: enumerate all of the possibilities and use alternation.

```
^(-\d+\.\d*[1-9]\d*|-\d*[1-9]\d*\.\d+|^\d+\.\d+)$
```

Note that your rules permit matching leading zeroes on a number, for example, `01.1` or `-01.0`. You can reject these with the even more crude

```
^(-?0\.\d*[1-9]\d*|-[1-9]\d*\.\d*[1-9]\d*|-[1-9]\d*\.\d+|^[1-9]\d*\.\d+|0.0+)$
```

Tests:

```js
const permissive = /^(-\d+\.\d*[1-9]\d*|-\d*[1-9]\d*\.\d+|^\d+\.\d+)$/;
const strict = /^(-?0\.\d*[1-9]\d*|-[1-9]\d*\.\d*[1-9]\d*|-[1-9]\d*\.\d+|^[1-9]\d*\.\d+|0.0+)$/;

`
0.0
0.00
0.001
0.12
1.00
1.12
-0.123
-1.000
-1.123
10.10
2.2
-2.2
0.00
-10.010
0.101

-0.0
-0.00
-0.000
-2.
.0
-.0
.012
1.
12.
00.
0.

-001.0
-01.0
01.1
010.1010
000.000
00.0
`.split("\n").filter(e => e).forEach(test => 
  console.log(
    test, "=> permissive:", permissive.test(test), 
    "... strict:", strict.test(test)
  )
);
```